# Failed to transfer some file with mput on sftp

Tags: bash, sftp, heredoc

I have a problem with my script that allows me to transfer several excel files with `SFTP`, every day some file is not transmitted, it's not a problem of file content or name.

Here is the code:

```bash
sshpass -f password/pass_sftp sftp $SFTP_USER@$SFTP_HOST << EOF
cd /store/availability
mput *.csv
bye
EOF
```

Do you have any idea what it could be ?

Comment: Try quoting the first `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

The proper form of use for the command, for [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) to use "EOF" as the pattern to indicate **end of input**, is to use the combination "**<<-**" followed by the **{string}**.

Your first line should read as:

```
sshpass -f password/pass_sftp sftp $SFTP_USER@$SFTP_HOST <<-EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) construct is sometimes misleading with interactive programs as you may face synchronization problems. That is to say that the interactive programs may not accept data until it prompts it or it can flush out the data received so far before displaying its prompt. This is why using a utility like [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) which simulates an operator in front of the interactive tool is more robust.

Let's consider the following interactive program example which prompts for a first and a last name and simulates some activity between the two inputs:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your first name: "
read fname

# Do some actions here and make some cleanup in the input buffer
read -t 1 -n 1000 garbage

echo "Enter your last name: "
read lname

echo you have entered $fname $lname
```

If we run it interactively, it works fine:

```
$ ./interact.sh 
Enter your first name: 
azerty
Enter your last name: 
qwerty
you have entered azerty qwerty
```

But if we run it with an `heredoc`, it fails because the second input arrives too early:

```
$ ./interact.sh <<EOF
> azerty
> qwerty
> EOF
Enter your first name: 
Enter your last name: 
you have entered azerty
```

The `heredoc` does not provide the ability to synchronize with the displayed prompts.
With an `expect` script, it is possible to wait for the display of the prompts before entering the answers as a human being would do. Let's consider the following to automate *interact.sh*:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1
spawn ./interact.sh
expect "first name:"
send "azerty\n"
expect "last name:"
send "qwerty\n"
expect eof
```

The execution result is the same as if a human interacted:

```
$ ./exp
spawn ./interact.sh
Enter your first name: 
azerty
Enter your last name: 
qwerty
you have entered azerty qwerty
```